# How to I close down a python server built using flask

Tags: python, flask

When I run this simple code:

`from flask import Flask,render_template`

`app = Flask(__name__)`

`@app.route('/')`
`def index():
    return 'this is the homepage'`

`if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0",port=8080)`

It works fine but when I close it using ctrl+z in the terminal and try to run it again I get `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

So I tried changing the port address and re-running it which works for some of the port numbers I enter. But I want to know a graceful way to clear the address being used by previous program so that it is free for the current one. 
Also is what is the apt way to shutdown a server and free the port address.

Kindly tell a simple way to do so OR explain the method used fully because I read solutions to similar problems but didn't understand any of it.

When I run
`netstat -tulpn`
The output is :

`(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3689            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4361/rhythmbox

tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

tcp6       0      0 :::3689                 :::*                    LISTEN      4361/rhythmbox

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3891/chrome

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39223           0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58140           0.0.0.0:*                           -

udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                3891/chrome

udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -

udp6       0      0 :::41938                :::*                                -`

I'm not sure how to interpret it.

the output of `ps aux | grep 8080` 
is :

`shreyash 22402  0.0  0.0  14224   928 pts/2    S+   01:20   0:00 grep --color=auto 8080`

I don't know how to interpret it.
Which one is the the process name and what is it's id?

Comment: 22402 is the process I’d. If you type ‘man ps’, this will tell you more about the ps process tool

Answer (score 3):

You need to type

```
fuser -n tcp -k 8080
```

in your terminal to terminate a flask process running on port 8080

Answer (score 2):

It stays alive because you're not closing it. With Ctrl+Z you're removing the execution from current terminal without killing a process.

To stop the execution use Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1):

If you typed Control+Z, you can type `fg` to move that process to the foreground again and kill it with Control+C. Z simply moves a current process to the background (`bg`). The `jobs` command will show the jobs running, including ones that are in the background.

If you don't have that window open anymore you can do:

```
ps aux | grep 8080
```

This will show the process(s) and its ID.

You can then kill the process using:

```
kill <that_process_id>
```

Comment: Which window are you talking about?

Comment: The one from which you originally launched the flask process

Comment: the browser window you mean?

Comment: Terminal window

Comment: How to interpret it's output. I've edited Q details.

Answer (score -1):

You will have another process listening on port 8080. You can check to see what that is and kill it. You can find processes listening on ports with `netstat -tulpn`. Before you do that, check to make sure you don't have another terminal window open with the running instance.

Comment: And how to interpret it's ouput?

Comment: If you show the output in your question, I can tell you the command to run.